# Вживання прийменника "по" в конструкціях мети

Tags: прийменники

Дізнався на [сайті](https://web.posibnyky.vntu.edu.ua/icgn/radomska_ukr_mova/3.htm), що:

> В українській мові прийменник по вживають з іменниками, займенниками, числівниками; конструкції з ним виражають такі відношення
>
> а) часові: по обіді, маю відпустку по 15 березня, приїду по святах
> (іноді можна замінити іменником у родовому відмінку з прийменником
> після – після свят);
>
> б) об’єктні: погладив по голівці, по коліна у воді;
>
> в) **мети: пішов по воду, пішла по гриби (і за грибами), поїхав по рибу;**
>
> г) кількісні відношення: по 25 осіб у групі; працює по 10 годин на
> добу;
>
> д) найчастіше вживаємо цей прийменник на позначення просторових
> відношень: по садочку ходжу

Також на цій сторінці також вказано:

> прийти по делу(рос) — прийти у справі(укр)

Але чому тоді "*піти по хліб*" [правильно](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRavIhdKoL0), але "*піти по справах*" [неправильно](https://youtu.be/Pu_kWFpU9fE?t=52), хоча в обох випадках використовують прийменник для позначення мети.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Коли ви йдете по хліб, ви маєте на меті купити собі хліба і в результаті мати хліб. Коли ви йдете по гриби, ви маєте на меті назбирати грибів і в результаті мати гриби. Коли ви йдете по хліб, по гриби, воду, по рибу і так далі, метою цього є мати оте, по що ви йшли.

Коли ви йдете "по справах", що є вашою метою?

Comment: Тобто Ви маєте на увазі, що то _інше значення мети_, так?

Comment: До речі, погоджуючись з Вами, що в словосполученнях «по хліб, по воду» і «у справах» дещо різні значення мети, додам ще одну думку: [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах про оце «по хліб, по воду»](http://sum.in.ua/s/po) каже, що (окрім того, що використовується при вказуванні саме на предмет, особу, а не на будь-яку мету) воно сполучається зі знахідним відмінком — тобто навіть якби іменник «справа / справи» був частиною ряду «по хліб, по воду, по…», то було б «по справ**у** / по справ**и**», а не «по справ**і** / по справ**ах**».

Comment: Так, погоджуюсь.